# Complex conjugates and polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

How can i prove that if $a+bi$ is a root of a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, then $a-bi$ is a root too? And, this property holds for another kind of functions?

Comment: Well, $i$ is a root of the polynomial $z-i$, but $-i$ isn't. First you want some criterion to eliminate polynomials like $z-i$.

Comment: Where are the coefficients? $ See, (x+2i)(x+3i) = 0 $.

Comment: I see you edited the question to stipulate $f(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that $\overline{z + w} = \overline{z} + \overline{w}$ and $\overline{z  w} = \overline{z} * \overline{w}$. As the coefficient $ \in \mathbb{R}$, $\overline{a*z} = a*\overline{z}$ and from this $\overline{z}$ is root too.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kz^k$. If $a+bi$ is a root of $f$, then
$$
f(a+bi) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(a+bi)^k = 0. 
$$
Now taking the complex conjugate of both sides gives us that
$$
\overline{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k(a+bi)^k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \overline{a_k(a+bi)^k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \overline a_k(\overline{a+bi})^k = \sum_{k=0}^na_k(a-bi)^k = \overline{0} = 0. 
$$
This means that $a-bi$ is also a root of the original polynomial.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not clear. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Look at $z^2 - i$; its roots are $r _ 1 = \cos(\pi /4) + i \sin (\pi /4)$ and $r_2 = -r_1$.  Note that $r_2 \ne \bar r_1$!

Comment: This only works when all the $a_k$ are real.

Comment: And for this case. how can i prove it?

Comment: I edited the answer to complete the proof. The statement isn't true when the coefficients are not all real.